# Can I buy a district after landing there by taking the train?

Tags: monopoly-city

In Monopoly City can I buy a district after landing there taking the train via a station?

**Background:**
I rolled the dice, went forward and ended up on a district owned by me that includes a train station. I decided to take the train to *Diamond Hills* which had a train station as well, but was not owned by anyone yet. Can I now purchase *Diamond Hills*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the rules specifically tell you you can. Under the *Where Did You Land* [section on (page 7)](http://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad288661c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/426C634219B9F3691090C1DA1F9FAF9F.pdf)

> **A district you own:**
>
> Do nothing unless there is a railroad on it. If so, you can immediately move to any other district with a railroad on it and buy it or auction it (if it is unowned) or pay rent (if it belongs to another player).

Comment: haha obviously. During our game of yesterday I read the station rules on page 9 and couldn't find the answer. So we applied common sense and came up with a house rule. The rules on page 7 are very clear though. Thanks for pointing them out to me.